# Why does the command php artisan make:auth not work?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Does someone know why this command gets aborted when I enter it?

D:\sites_laravel\vinyl_shop>php artisan make:auth

> The [auth/login.blade.php] view already exists. Do you want to replace it? (yes/no) [no]:
>   Aborted.

error message

[image]

Comment: The thing is... it instantly aborts the process.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: The laravel version i'm running is 5.8

Comment: or is it this ur looking for? Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '9.1.0' is up to date

Comment: That error is specifically saying that the resources that would be created by running the command already exist in your project, are you certain you havent run this command before, or that some other process didnt run it for you?

Comment: close your project and try again. your command already runs once and you are trying for the second time.

Comment: i had a similar issue which got resolved by the following command 
`
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
`

Answer (score 2):

Delete everything inside resources/views/auth folder.
Delete app.blade.php from layouts folder.

Then Try it again.

100% working.

Comment: Thank, I only remove app.blade.php and run `php artisan ui:auth` (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940983/what-is-the-difference-between-php-artisan-ui-vue-auth-command-and-php-arti ) and check diff on app.blade to adapt it

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 6 the auth command updated, it good for you to update your laravel.
and for authentication you need first do this:

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

and then run this:

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

If your laravel version is less than 6, just delete the files related to authentication from  `resources/views/auth`, then it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a probleme with login file in views folder ,if you can remove it, remove it and also
verify if your composer is installed you can install it by

```
composer install
```

and also your System auth by

```
composer require laravel/ui "^2.0" --dev
```

*this commande it works for laravel 7*

but look for the new version in [new version][1]

and if you in a new version of laravel 7+ just use :

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```