# Error installing backpack for laravel 6, problem with elfinder

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm trying to **install backpack-for-laravel** but can't get it to work. I followed the instructions but I get this when running

```
php artisan backpack:install
```

[image]

It's not giving me the option to say yes or no, it just aborts.

I'm running **backpack 4.0 on Laravel 6**

Comment: Well that's a bummer. I've just tested and the process went fine for me (I've hit Enter when asked if I want to install elfinder). I see you're using Windows & WAMP - I'll ask someone with the same dev env to test, maybe it's related to that. I'll be back.

Comment: I've also added a Bug Report here - https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/2416

Answer (score 0):

Try again, and answer the question with `no` (or `yes` if that's what you want). It looks like the Symphony package that Laravel uses for asking questions could have a problem with Windows in certain configurations.

Comment: I don't get a chance to answer yes or no it just says aborted

Comment: Hmm I'm sorry to hear that. I'm pretty sure it's not something Backpack-specific - it must be related to your local setup. I see there are other reports of getting Aborted for other artisan commands, but no solution I'm afraid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59506288/why-does-the-command-php-artisan-makeauth-not-work and https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2192 - I'm afraid there's nothing more I can do to help. I hope someone who's had the same problem can come across this and help out. I'll keep the bug report open too, maybe someone sees it there.