# What is the difference between "php artisan ui vue --auth" command and "php artisan ui:auth"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-8

What is the difference between running these two commands?

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

VS:

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

I know both make authentication folders but which one should I run for using Laravel 8? And what is the main difference?

Comment: `ui:auth` is a method of package `laravel/ui`, which has been dropped since Laravel 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php artisan ui vue --auth -> The command will generate the auth routes and a VueJs starter template.

php artisan ui:auth -> The command will generate the auth routes, a HomeController, auth views, and a app.blade.php layout file.

check out the documentation here- https://medium.com/@agavitalis/php-artisan-make-auth-command-is-not-defined-laravel-6-b51adcc6356d

Jetstream will take care of scaffolding your entire authentication system!- this a documentation of laravel 8 version.

check the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication

Answer (score 1):

php artisan ui vue --auth command:

- This command sets up a Laravel project with Vue.js as the frontend framework and includes authentication scaffolding.
- It generates the necessary files and configurations to enable user registration, login, and other authentication-related features with Vue.js components.

php artisan ui:auth command:

- This command is similar to php artisan ui vue --auth.
- It sets up authentication scaffolding, but it defaults to using Laravel's Blade templating engine for the views instead of Vue.js.

php artisan make:auth command:

- This command is available in older versions of Laravel (before Laravel 8).
- It generates authentication scaffolding, including controllers, views, and routes, but it doesn't include frontend frameworks like Vue.js by default.

In summary, all three commands are used to set up authentication features in a Laravel application, but they differ in the default frontend technology (Blade or Vue.js) and the way they're invoked. If you're using Laravel 8 or newer, it's recommended to use php artisan ui vue --auth or php artisan ui:auth depending on your preferred frontend technology. If you're using an older version of Laravel, php artisan make:auth was the common approach.